# SQL - Inserting into table with one row as select and another as same value

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert multiple rows into a table using a select statement for one value, with the other value being the same value in every row.

```
INSERT 
        INTO INVTBL (invid, staticid)
        VALUES
        (SELECT invid from INVENTORYTBL 
        WHERE invid in (select id from PARTS WHERE partcode like '%OEA'), 126)
```

New to SQL - thanks for any help to get me going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `values` clause if the source is a select statement:

```
insert into invtbl (invid, staticid)
select invid, 126
from INVENTORYTBL 
WHERE invid in (select id from PARTS WHERE partcode like '%OEA')
```